# How many minimum spanning tree of following graph is possible.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> How many minimum spanning tree of following graph is possible.

[image]

---

My attempt:

I've tried it manually as :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Therefore,

Total possible number of minimum spanning trees are $=2\times2\times2+2\times2+2=8+4+2=14$

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the edge of weight $7$, since it could be replaced by the other edges of the rectangle, whose weights add to $6$. The resulting graph has $3$ cut vertices, and all minimal spanning trees in the $4$ components they separate can be arbitrarily combined. From left to right, there are $3$, $1$, $3$ and $2$ minimal spanning trees for the components, for a total of $3\cdot1\cdot3\cdot2=18$. (You were missing $4$ trees from the case where you would have had "$2$ options" in the first component and the two diagonal edges in the third component.)